# How can I get the QMenu and QActions from a QwtPlot

Tags: c++, qt, qmenu, qtestlib, qaction

I have a **QwtPlot** widget that shows a **QMenu** with some **QActions** when the user clicks on it with the right mouse button:

[image]

Now, I need to implement an automated function to test it.

**How can I get access to the QMenu and QActions from the QwtPlot widget?**

I already tried the command:

```
QTest::mouseClick(myQwtPlot, Qt::RightButton, Qt::NoModifier, QPoint(), 30);
```

But the **QMenu** doesn't appear.

Qt version 5.3.2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access a QAction using the QtTest lib?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40305610/how-to-access-a-qaction-using-the-qttest-lib)

Comment: Thanks, actually I asked this question again because I didn't receive an answer here.