# How to access a QAction using the QtTest lib?

Tags: qt, qmenu, qtestlib, qaction, qttest

I have a pop-up menu in a `QTableWidget` (resultTable). In the constructor of my class I set the context menu policy:

```
resultTable->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(resultTable, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(QPoint)), this, SLOT(popUpMenuResultTable(QPoint)));
```

The `popUpMenuResultTable` function:

```
void MyClass::popUpMenuResultTable(QPoint pos)
{
    QMenu menu;
    QAction* actionExport = menu.addAction(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/FileIcon.png"), tr("Export"));
    connect(actionExport, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(exportResultsTable()));
    menu.popup(pos);
    menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
}
```

Now, I need to implement a function to test my GUI using  the **QtTest** lib.

How can I produce the same result as a user by right clicking on my **resultTable**? Basically, I need to get access to the `actionExport` (`QAction`) and trigger it.

For example:

[image]

I already tried:

```
QTest::mouseClick(resultTable, Qt::RightButton, Qt::NoModifier, pos, delay);
```

but it does not show the `QMenu`.

I'm using Qt 5.3.2.

Comment: Have you tried sending a context menu event to the widget?
I.e. creating a `QContextMenuEvent` and the sending it with `QCoreApplication::sendEvent()` or `QCoreApplication::postEvent()`

Comment: No, I haven't tried it. Can you provide a brief example of how can I do that? Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe not entirely what you are after but an alternative approach that is easier to test.

Instead of creating the menu manually you register the actions with the widgets and use `Qt::ActionContextMenu`:

```
// e.g. in the widget's constructor
resultTable->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::ActionsContextMenu);

QAction* actionExport = menu.addAction(QIcon(":/new/prefix1/FileIcon.png"), tr("Export"));
connect(actionExport, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(exportResultsTable()));
resultTable->addAction(actionExport);
```

Then you either add an accessor to your widget that returns `resultTable->actions()` or just make `actionExport` a member of your class.
Once your test code has access to the action it can simply call its trigger `trigger()` method.